# How to test for people with lots of Facebook friends?

Tags: testing, facebook-graph-api

We're working on a website that fetches a fair bit of info from Facebook for users and their friends. We'll soon be inviting people with a lot of friends. More than any of us have, and more than Facebook allows you to create with their test account API.

What's the best way to test given that? Is there some trick to create test more users, or to add extra friends to a test account? Are there real people with 5000 friends we can pay to authorize our app? Or are we stuck just simulating large responses and hoping that Facebook responds similarly in production for somebody with 5k friends?

Comment: No, test users can only be friends of other test users for that app. BTW, how are you going to be sending the invites?

Comment: did you managed to test this ?

Comment: At the time, we simulated large responses for our automated load tests, and also had some logging that helped us notice when certain tasks were taking a long time for users with massive friend lists. It's been a while though, so perhaps things are better.